# Stored procedure search parameter in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have got the MS SQL stored procedure, which is designed to return the results in XML showing all the applicants who are `'sales'`.

There are filters on the page to drill down the results one being a search (`sString`).

The desired behavior is:

- If `sString` is `null`, it should return all the results;
- If `sString` is `not null`, it should make `sString` to the show the found fields.

The SP does not work as expected: it always returns all the results regardless of `sString` value.

MS SQL Code of the SP:

```
WITH OrderedMatches AS
(

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MB.Member_Registered DESC) AS RowNumber, 
    MB.Member_ID,
    MB.Member_Name, MB.Member_Mobile, MB.Member_Propertytosell, MB.Member_Propertytosell_Details, MB.Member_ExistingBuytoLet, MB.Member_TalkingPoints,
    MB.Member_Registered, MB.Member_Funding, MB.Member_Active, MB.Member_Last_Contacted, MB.Member_Situation

    FROM dbo.Member_Base MB INNER JOIN dbo.Member_Criteria MC ON MC.Member_ID = MB.Member_ID

    WHERE MB.Member_Active = 1 AND MC.Criteria_Section = 'sales' 
    AND (
        @sType = 'a'
        OR (
            @sType = 'b' AND MB.Member_Propertytosell = 1
        )
        OR (
            @sType = 'c' AND MB.Member_ExistingBuytoLet = 1
        )   

    )
    OR (
        MB.Member_Name LIKE '%' + @sString + '%' OR MB.Member_Mobile LIKE '%' + @sString + '%' OR MB.Member_Propertytosell_Details LIKE '%' + @sString + '%'
    )

)       

SELECT 
(
    SELECT 
        OM.Member_ID as "@id",
        OM.Member_Name as "@appname",
        OM.Member_Mobile as "@contact",
        OM.Member_Propertytosell as "@propts",
        OM.Member_Propertytosell_Details as "@proptsdetails",
        OM.Member_ExistingBuytoLet as "@existingBTL",
        OM.Member_TalkingPoints as "@talkingpoints",
        OM.Member_Registered as "@registered",
        OM.Member_Funding as "@funding",
        OM.Member_Active as "@active",
        OM.Member_Last_Contacted as "@lastcontact",
        OM.Member_Situation as "@situation"

    FROM OrderedMatches OM

    WHERE OM.RowNumber Between @nstart AND @nend
    FOR XML path ('applicant'), TYPE
),
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)  as "@titems"
    FROM OrderedMatches
    FOR XML path ('meta')
)
FOR XML PATH ('')


END
```

I suppose the SP is wrong but cant see at which part exactly.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning everything because you have `OR` between your `sString` condition and the rest of conditions in `WHERE`. Change your `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE MB.Member_Active = 1 AND MC.Criteria_Section = 'sales' 
AND (
    @sType = 'a'
    OR (
        @sType = 'b' AND MB.Member_Propertytosell = 1
    )
    OR (
        @sType = 'c' AND MB.Member_ExistingBuytoLet = 1
    )   

)
AND (@sString IS NULL 
    OR
    (
        MB.Member_Name LIKE '%' + @sString + '%' OR MB.Member_Mobile LIKE '%' + @sString + '%' OR MB.Member_Propertytosell_Details LIKE '%' + @sString + '%'
    )
)
```